# Overloaded function ambiguity

Tags: c++, boost

Firstly I should point out that this is my first stackoverflow question, so please bear with me.

I'm having some problems overloading a function in c++. I'm trying to create a function with the following prototypes:

```
void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::string>, int);

void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>, int);

void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>, int);

void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::string>, bool, int);
```

I originally wanted the last overload (the one with the boolean) to accept a boost::regex instead of a string vector;

```
void push_at_command(std::string, boost::regex, int);
```

but ran into ambiguity errors... so just to quickly get the code 'working' I thought I'd add a prototype to accept a flag, and use the first element in the vector to store a regex string, but I seem to be running into similar problems having the boolean.

This is how I'm trying to call these various overloads:

```
push_at_command(
    "AT?S", 
    boost::assign::list_of("(\\d{3}.\\d{3})"),
    true,
    0);
push_at_command(
    "AT?S", 
    boost::assign::list_of("L11")("L12"),
    0);
push_at_command(
    "AT?S", 
    boost::assign::list_of("L11"),
    boost::assign::list_of("L21")("L22"),
    0);
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘push_at_command(const char [5], boost::assign_detail::generic_list<char [4]>, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<char [4]>, int)’ is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
note: void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, int)
note: void push_at_command(std::string, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, bool, int)
```

... which relates to the third function call.

Just to note, I had no problems before I added the overload with the bool (or changing the string vector to regex).

I am assuming the problem has something to do with me using boost::assign in the function call, and I realise that I don't need to, but I really need 'single line' function calls.
... Any advice welcome, as I am fairly new to C++.

Thanks

Comment: My personal tip: Your life will be happier if you avoid syntactic overloading.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think you may be right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as seen in the boost documentation, `But what if we need to initialize a container? This is where list_of() comes into play. With list_of() we can create anonymous lists that automatically converts to any container:`

In this case you don't *want* to be able to convert to any container,  you want specifically s vector. Since you have this convertible type instead, it can't decide if it should convert to bool or vector, making the call ambiguous.

If you *really* want to continue with the overload set you've created (please take a step back and reconsider your approach using a flag) you'll need to specifically assign the list of into a vector (I'm assuming here that `list_of` provides a conversion operator to vector):

```
push_at_command(
    "AT?S", 
    boost::assign::list_of("L11"),
    std::vector<std::string>(boost::assign::list_of("L21")("L22")),
    0);
```

Comment: But if you keep only the function that takes bool, you'll get

 error: invalid cast from type `std::_Deque_iterator<const char*, const char*&, const char**>' to type `bool'.

this indicates that it cannot be converted to bool

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have now restructured and redesigned my program to not use these overloads.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you what the problem is. The call that's getting into trouble is the third one:

```
push_at_command(
    "AT?S", 
    boost::assign::list_of("L11"),
    boost::assign::list_of("L21")("L22"),
    0);
```

and the problem is that it can match **both** the third and fourth versions of `push_at_command`. They differ in the type of the third argument: one takes a `vector` and the other takes `bool`.

So the issue is that `boost::assign::list_of("L21")("L22)` can be converted to a `vector` and it can be converted to `bool`, and the rules do not prefer one of those conversions over the other. In a case like this, you have to help the compiler out, with a `static_cast` to the desired type. Or rethink the organization of these functions, and maybe re-order the arguments so that you don't get an ambiguity. (That's why, for example, `std::string` has a constructor that takes `(int, char)` and no constructor for a single `char`, which leads to ambiguities; it's an awkward interface, driven by too many overloads).

Comment: Please see my question to Mark B. It is relevant to your answer too.